# Why are notifications appearing in the invisible black zone above my monitor?

Tags: compiz, multiple-monitors, notify-osd

I've got two monitors, with the right side one being slightly lower in the display settings. However any notifications I receive from notify-osd (including pidgin, notify-send etc) are sent to the top-most part of the right monitor screen, which results it in being invisible.

[image: Top Right invisible notification]

And here's a pic of my monitor preferences :
[image]

I'd earlier used the Wallpaper plugin in compiz to stitch my desktops, and then uninstalled compiz-extras. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 in classic mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug, and the inability to configure the position of notify-osd to prevent it happening is a feature.

Luckily, in the spirit of open source, someone has created a patched version that can be configured and positioned manually:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html

Comment: Link to bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/779612

Comment: This bug is now fixed! Yay!